# Autofac + .NET Core - consume InstancePerHttpRequest from singleton/root scope

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core, autofac, serilog

I am using Serilog with Autofac and .NET Core. I am using a serilog enricher, which requires an instance during setup.

```
        var enricher = new ContextEnricher();

        Configuration = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.ControlledBy(new LoggingLevelSwitch { MinimumLevel = logLevel })
            .Enrich.WithThreadId()
            .Enrich.With(enricher)
            .WriteTo.ApplicationInsightsTraces(applicationInsightsKey)
            .WriteTo.Console();

        Log.Logger = Configuration.CreateLogger();
```

I ideally want my logger to be built before my DI container is built so that I can trap errors as soon as possible. The issue is that my log enricher needs to consume something in RequestScope, but is set up before DI even takes place. The obvious direction is to use a factory function after the container is built.

```
public class ContextEnricher : IContextEnricher
{
    public Func<ICorrelationProvider> GetCorrelationProvider { get; set; }

    public void Enrich(LogEvent logEvent, ILogEventPropertyFactory propertyFactory)
    {
        if (GetCorrelationProvider == null) return;

        var correlationProvider = GetCorrelationProvider();

        if (correlationProvider == null) return;

        logEvent.AddOrUpdateProperty(new LogEventProperty("CorrelationId", new ScalarValue(correlationProvider.CorrelationId)));
    }
}
```

I based this solution off of this article: https://robdmoore.id.au/blog/2013/03/23/resolving-request-scoped-objects-into-a-singleton-with-autofac

The problem is, the article uses:

```
 return () => DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<T>();
```

As the factory function - but the DependencyResolver does not exist in .NET Core.

I have tried using:

```
 return () => Container.Resolve<T>();
```

But get this runtime error:

> No scope with a tag matching 'AutofacWebRequest' is visible from the
>   scope in which the instance was requested. If you see this during
>   execution of a web application, it generally indicates that a
>   component registered as per-HTTP request is being requested by a
>   SingleInstance() component (or a similar scenario). Under the web
>   integration always request dependencies from the dependency resolver
>   or the request lifetime scope, never from the container itself.

What is the correct way to achieve this in .NET Core without access to the dependency resolver?

Comment: [Have you read the docs?](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html) It's not instance per request in ASP.NET Core - it's instance per lifetime scope.

Comment: @user3689167 - It feels like you chose inappropriate technology to get that job done. If you need to log something from a http request then middleware should be used. Please take a look at [this example](https://blog.getseq.net/smart-logging-middleware-for-asp-net-core/) on how to do this.